# Consume a SOAP Webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, soap

Hi I'm trying to implement a SOAP call, by using an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString  *textFieldCelcisus = @"0";
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             " <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                             "<Celsius>%@</Celsius>\n"
                             "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n" ,textFieldCelcisus];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        NSLog(@"Ok");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

It's say "Ok" in the console, but if I put a wrong url it's still say "Ok", I don't understand why.

### EDIT

Update, I did the delegate methods, I see no errors, but the message still "Ok"

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {


    receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString  *textFieldCelcisus = @"0";
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             " <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                             "<Celsius>%@</Celsius>\n"
                             "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n" ,textFieldCelcisus];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection ) //pointer returned from the [[NSURLConnection  alloc] init]
    {
        NSLog(@"Ok");//as long as the initializer returns not nil, this will print.
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse object.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection and the data object
    // by setting the properties (declared elsewhere)
    // to nil.  Note that a real-world app usually
    // requires the delegate to manage more than one
    // connection at a time, so these lines would
    // typically be replaced by code to iterate through
    // whatever data structures you are using.
    theConnection = nil;
    receivedData = nil;

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data
    // receivedData is declared as a property elsewhere
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",(unsigned long)[receivedData length]);

    // Release the connection and the data object
    // by setting the properties (declared elsewhere)
    // to nil.  Note that a real-world app usually
    // requires the delegate to manage more than one
    // connection at a time, so these lines would
    // typically be replaced by code to iterate through
    // whatever data structures you are using.
    theConnection = nil;
    receivedData = nil;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to implement many of the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods. See the docs for `NSURLConnection` for more details.

Comment: @rmaddy I have a problem with receiveData variable access look my edit please

Comment: @rmaddy no it's ok for the variable now

Comment: @rmaddy look my edit I still get "Ok"

Comment: Of course you still get "OK". The `NSURLConnection` instance is created regardless of the URL. You need to do error checking in the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is looking to see if "theConnection" is a valid pointer.

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection ) //pointer returned from the [[NSURLConnection  alloc] init]
    {
        NSLog(@"Ok");//as long as the initializer returns not nil, this will print.
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
```

you will need to implement the delegate methods for NSURLConnection to see what the result of the request was. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

connection:didFailWithError:
connection:didReceiveData:
connectionDidFinishLoading:

etc...

Comment: I have a problem with receiveData variable access look my edit please

Comment: No it's ok for the variable now

Comment: You are still basing your logic on the pointer value. pointers are memory addresses. you need to move your if statement to actually look at results of the URL request. right now you are just looking at the memory address of the object.